# vertical align middle isnt working, and hyperlink messes up formatting?

Tags: html, css

I want my text in the three link boxes to be vertically aligned in the middle - but they won't for some reason?

I also want the entire div each of the three sport options sit in, to be a clickable box. I have made "marathon" div clickable, but it messes up the alignment

What are these 2 problems ocurring?

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }/*
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   background: transparent;
   }*/
html,
body {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
}
.parent-container {
   min-height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   position:relative;
   background: black;
   text-align: center;

   margin: 0 auto;

}
.child-container{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 80%;
   height: 60%;
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   left: 10%;
   top: 20%;
   background: black;
   position: absolute;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   border-radius: 0%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.Marathon {
   top: 17.5%;
   height: 10%;
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   margin-top: auto;
}
.Marathon:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Hockey:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Cycling:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Hockey {
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   width: 50%;
   height: 10%;
   top: 45%;margin-top: auto;
}
.Cycling {
   height: 10%;
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   top: 72.5%;
   margin-top:auto;
   margin-bottom:auto;
}
 h1{
   color:#39ff14;
   font-family: 'Nunito';
   padding-top: 5%;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 10%;
}
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
.child-container a{
   color: #39ff14;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>My Map App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent-container"> 
 <h1>My Map App</h1>
 <div class="child-container">
    <a href="marathon.php"><div class="Marathon">Marathon</div></a>
    <div class="Hockey"><a href="hockey.php">Hockey</a></div>
       <div class="Cycling"><a href="cycling.php">Cycling</a></div>
      
  </div>
 
</div>









</body>
</html>
```

Also, I want my web app to show up nicely on my mobile. Currently, my web app shows nicely on my PC, but when I open on mobile, the title "My Map App" is tiny! How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance
PS, very new to this!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all those individual styles for Hockey, Cycling, and Marathon. And add this to your `.child-container` style:

```
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Though I wouldn't recommend something so general, a more global style for your links could look something like this:

```
.child-container > * {
    padding: 12px 10%;
    border: solid 2px #39ff14;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Lastly, add this to the head of your document so mobile isn't so zoomed out: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have updated my question with edited .css based on your suggestion! I've also added in the meta - works great, thanks! Any ideas on why my text isn't aligning-middle for the three links? Or how to make the entire box area clickable?

Comment: You need to remove the styles on .Hockey, .Cycling, .Marathon, They're being styled as if they were absolutely positioned. Remove all that stuff, and flexbox will automatically center them. Then, like in my example, if you targeted all direct children of `.child-container`, you could add the necessary padding, border, width, etc. for all of them.

Comment: Ah yes, its worked, although it squashes my spacing down a lot!

Comment: You can add spacing between buttons with margins in your css. Something like `margin: 15px auto;` on each button to help keep things relatively centered.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has a minor syntax error. Make sure to keep track of tags. In this case, the div tag was accidentally placed after the anchor tag in the marathon section of the html. If you have a bug with an html element- go to that class to see why it is different from the others.

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }/*
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   background: transparent;
   }*/
html,
body {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
}
.parent-container {
   min-height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   position:relative;
   background: black;
   text-align: center;

   margin: 0 auto;

}
.child-container{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 80%;
   height: 60%;
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   left: 10%;
   top: 20%;
   background: black;
   position: absolute;

   border-radius: 0%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.Marathon {
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 17.5%;
   height: 10%;
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   color: #39ff14;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-top: auto;
   border-radius: 0%;
}
.Marathon:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Hockey:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Cycling:hover{
   background: grey;
}
.Hockey {
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 45%;
   height: 10%;
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   color: #39ff14;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-top: auto;
   border-radius: 0%;
}
.Cycling {
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 72.5%;
   height: 10%;
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #39ff14 ;
   color: #39ff14;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-top: auto;
   border-radius: 0%;
}
.parent-container h1{
   color:#39ff14;
   font-family: 'Nunito';
padding-top: 5%;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 10%;

}
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
.child-container a{
   color: #39ff14;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>My Map App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent-container"> 
 <h1>My Map App</h1>
<div class="child-container">
   <div class="Marathon"><a href="marathon.php">Marathon</a></div>
   <div class="Hockey"><a href="hockey.php">Hockey</a></div>
   <div class="Cycling"><a href="cycling.php">Cycling</a></div>
  
 </div>
 
</div>









</body>
</html>
```

You probably want to change the box styles so that they look nicer.

As for the mobile vs desktop problem look into this:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! That was actually deliberate - I want the entire box to be "clickable" for the link! I placed the anchor tag on the outside of the div in the hope it would make the entire div clickable - it did, but it messed up my formatting - one question was how to I make the entire box clickable. Thank you - ill have a read!

Answer (score 0):

**How about something super simple as this?**

```
<a>                      //This will act as your button container
  <p>Cycling</p>         // Here goes the name
</a>
```

Give style of Button to your `<a>`, hence it will function as a button.

> Keep CSS as simple as you could.

```css
* {
  background: black;
}

.parent-container {
  margin: 40px;
}

.parent-container h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #39ff14;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #39ff14;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.child-container a {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid #39ff14;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  width: 30%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Marathon {
  text-align: center;
  color: #39ff14;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.Hockey {
  color: #39ff14;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.Cycling {
  color: #39ff14;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <h1>My Map App</h1>
  <div class="child-container">
    <a href="marathon.php">
      <p class="Marathon">Marathon</p>
    </a>
    <a href="hockey.php">
      <p class="Hockey">Hockey</p>
    </a>
    <a href="cycling.php">
      <p class="Cycling">Cycling</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```